# Dual Space and Dual Basis

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, dual-spaces

Let V be a finite dimensional vector space over a field F.  Let $V^*$ be the dual space of $V$. Consider the dual basis $f_i$ given by
$$
f_i(v_j)=1\;\text{if}\;i=j\;\text{and}\;0\;\text{if}\;i\neq j
$$ 
Consider the following expression $a_1f_1+....+a_nf_n=0$
Then evaluating the maps at each basis $v_i$ we get $a_i=0$
The question is, are the scalars assumed to be constant?

Edit:
Read the following edit, please: 
what I'm essentially asking is  what if the scalars depended on the input vector, would the proof still hold?

Comment: If the $f_i$ form a basis, then by definition, $\sum a_i f_i = 0$ implies $a_i = 0$ for all $i$, i.e., they're linearly independent. I'm not sure what your last question means in relation to the previous assumptions.

Comment: @Derek Allums, well if they weren't constants, then surely they won't always be 0.

Comment: @topologicalmagician This depends on the context, but probably yes, those are constants.

Comment: Its a linear combination of the linear functionals and so the $a_i$'s are scalars.

Comment: @Westenfux, read the edit please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will interpret your question as asking what happens when instead of taking the $a_i\in F$, we take $a_i \in V^*$, and whether then $a_1f_1 + \cdots + a_nf_n = 0$ implies $a_i = 0$ for all $i$. Consider $a_1 = f_2$, $a_2 = -f_1$, $a_i = 0$ otherwise. Clearly $a_1f_1 + \ldots + a_nf_n = f_2f_1 - f_1f_2 = 0$, but $a_1, a_2 \neq 0$. Note that once you do this though, the $a_if_i$ are not necessarily elements in the dual space anymore, as for example for any nonzero $f \in V^*$, we have that $f^2$ is not linear (so in particular, I don't know if there is any reason to consider this)

Comment: That is precisely what I was looking for.